# Pass associative array as parameter list to script

Tags: bash, parameter, associative-array

In a script I have an associative array like:

```
declare -A VARS=( ["key1"]="value1" ["key2"]="value" )
```

Is there a single command to transform that into a parameter list in the form

```
--key1=value1 --key2=value2
```

without having to manually re-write

```
 --key1="${VARS[key1]}" --key2="${VARS[key2]}"
```

the use-case I had in mind was to pass the array to a script as a list of parameters, like

```
my_script.sh $(to_param_list $VARS)
```

To expand on the comment I made on @Kusalananda answer, my exact use case is as follows: I have a script which is used to build a self-extracting installer using makeself, and this script receives some parameters which are to be separated between:

- parameters for the script itself
- parameters for the installer inside the self-extracting installer

The scripts then builds the installer like this:

```
to_param_list installer_param_list installer_param_array
./makeself ./path/to/sourcedir ./path/to/created/installer "My installer" ./path/to/install/inside/package "${installer_param_list[@]}"
```

However, I have tested the parameter passing with a very simple installer script inside the package:

```
while ! -z "$1" ; do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

and passing an array like:

```
installer_param_array=( ["upgrade-from"]="19 .2.0" ["upgrade-to"]="19.3.0" )
```

results in this output:

```
--upgrade-to=19.3.0
--upgrade-from=19
.2.0
```

Comment: It does not answer the question, but another way (in bash, one of the tags) is `my_script.sh  "$(declare -p thearray)$"`. In `myscript.sh`  you read it with `source /dev/stdin <<<"$1"` Then you have `thearray` in your script. You can have other arguments alongside the array.  You can pass many variables: `my_script.sh "$(declare -p var1 var2 ...)"` in this single argument.

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow: How to pass an associative array as argument to a function in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4069188/4561887). I've written [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71060913/4561887) which shows how to manually serialize and deserialize (parse) an associative array in bash. This may be related to some people's problems who land on this question in their Google searches.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a helper function:

```
#!/bin/bash

to_param_list () {
    declare -n outlist=$1
    declare -n inhash=$2

    for param in "${!inhash[@]}"; do
        outlist+=( "--$param=${inhash[$param]}" )
    done
}

declare -A my_vars=( ["key1"]="value1" ["key2"]="value" )

to_param_list list my_vars
my_script.sh "${list[@]}"
```

The final command in the above script would expand to the equivalent of having written

```
my_script.sh "--key2=value" "--key1=value1"
```

The `to_param_list` function takes the *name* of an array variable and the *name* of an associative array variable and uses these to create two "name reference" variables in the function (namerefs were introduced in `bash` release 4.3).  These are then use to populate the given array variable with the keys and values in the appropriate format from the associative array.

The loop in the function iterates over `"${!inhash[@]}"`, which is the list of individually quoted keys in your associative array.

Once the function call returns, the script would use the array to call your other script or command.

Running the above with

```
declare -A my_vars=( ["key1"]="hello world" ["key2"]="some thing" ["key3"]="* * *" )

to_param_list list my_vars
printf 'Arg: %s\n' "${list[@]}"
```

the script would output

```
Arg: --key2=some thing
Arg: --key3=* * *
Arg: --key1=hello world
```

This shows that the options are generated without word splitting or filename globbing coming into effect.  It also shows that the order of the keys may not be preserved since accessing the keys out of an associative array will do so in a fairly random order.

---

You can't really use a command substitution safely here as the result of it would be a single string.  If unquoted, this string would then be split on whitespace characters (by default), which would additionally split both the keys and values of your associative array.  The shell would also perform filename globbing on the resulting words.  Double quoting the command substitution would not help as that would result in calling your `my_script.sh` with a *single* argument.

---

**Regarding your issue with `makeself`**:

The `makeself` script does this with the arguments to your installer script:

```
SCRIPTARGS="$*"
```

This saves the arguments as a string in `$SCRIPTARGS` (concatenated, separated by spaces).  This later gets inserted into the self-extracting archive as-is.  For the options to be parsed correctly when they are *re-evaluated* (which they are when running the installer), you will have to provide an *extra* set of quotes in the values of the parameters for them to be properly delimited.

```
installer_param_array=( ["upgrade-from"]="'19 .2.0'" ["upgrade-to"]="'19.3.0'" )
```

Note that this is not a bug in my code. It's just a side effect of `makeself` producing *shell code* based on user-supplied values.

Ideally, the `makeself` script should have written each of the provided arguments with an extra set of quotes around them, but it doesn't, presumable because it's difficult to know what effect that may have.  Instead, it leaves it to the user to provide these extra quotes.

Rerunning my test from above, but now with

```
declare -A my_vars=( ["key1"]="'hello world'" ["key2"]="'some value'" ["key3"]="'* * *'" )

to_param_list list my_vars
printf 'Arg: %s\n' "${list[@]}"
```

produces

```
Arg: --key2='some value'
Arg: --key3='* * *'
Arg: --key1='hello world'
```

You can see that *these* strings, when *re-evaluated* by the shell, would not get split on spaces.

Obviously, you could use your initial associative array and instead add the quotes in the `to_param_list` function by changing

```
outlist+=( "--$param=${inhash[$param]}" )
```

into

```
outlist+=( "--$param='${inhash[$param]}'" )
```

Either of these changes to your code would include the single quotes in the values of the options, so a re-evaluation of the values would become *necessary*.

Comment: I tried your solution, however if one of the values in the starting associative array contains any space, the resulting command will break up

Comment: @MatteoTassinari No it would not. If it does, then you have forgotten the double quotes in `"--$param=${inhash[$param]}"` or in `"${list[@]}"`, or the script that receives the options does something wrong in parsing them.

Comment: I can confirm that I used the quotes as you are showing, these parameters are passed to https://github.com/megastep/makeself to create an installer which, when executes, invokes a script with the given parametes, perhaps in this passage something goes wrong

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Note that the options to that tool that take arguments should have no `=` between the option name and the argument.  This means that the `"--$param=${inhash[$param]}"` in my code changes to `"--$param" "${inhash[$param]}"` (two separate strings are added to the resulting array).   I _think_ this the issue, without seeing what you are seeing.

Comment: No, it's not that, I'll try to edit my question to better show my use-case.

Comment: I added my actual use-case and the error I'm having

Comment: @MatteoTassinari See update.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I ended up doing